# Undefined reference to constructor

Tags: c++, g++

I'm a Java developer experimenting with C++.

I just created a new class. In my other class I want to have list where I can store Filter objects.

**Filter.h**

```
#ifndef FILTER_H_
#define FILTER_H_

class Filter {
public:
  Filter(int id);
  int id;
  ~Filter();

};

#endif /* FILTER_H_ */
```

**Filter.cpp**

```
#include "Filter.h"

Filter::Filter(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
Filter::~Filter() {
}
```

**Cars.h**

```
#include "Filter.h"
...
...
private:
  std::vector<Filter> filters;
```

**Cars.cpp**

so in a function here I try to do this:

```
int id = 2;
Filter *filter = new Filter(id);
```

which generate this error:

```
Cars.cpp:120: undefined reference to `Filter::Filter(int)'
stl_construct.h:83: undefined reference to `Filter::~Filter()'
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: This will not even compile. Are you sure, this is the real code? If so, you're compiling the project in a wrong way. How you do this?

Comment: can you post your g++ build instructions?

Comment: If you're serious about C++, please pick up a good book and learn it properly. The way you're going, you'll end up with a horrible, leaking, buggy java-like mess. C++ *is not the same* as Java.

Comment: Please, *please* get [a good book on C++](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) and forget everything you know from Java. C++ values completely different things, and you'll only hurt your C++ experience if you try to program the same way as you did in Java.

Comment: also `this` is a pointer so you need to use `this->id = id` instead of `this.id = id`

Comment: @mathematician1975: Better just use the mem-initializer-list: `Filter(int id) : id(id) {}`.

Comment: Okay, I realize this was not the best way to form my question then. What's the best way to use an object with some variables in an already existing class. The only thing I want is to make a Filter object, or something similar which can hold some variables. Any other way to go around this? Is there really no other solution to this than reading a book? I'm grateful for all answers, but I have no big plans of studying c++ over a longer period.

Comment: @Ole-M: Your specific problem is because of the way you are building your code. If you were building it the right way you would not be getting the errors above. The actual problem seems to be that you are not including Filter.cpp in your build. Unlike Java every C++ compiler is different. You need to learn how to use the compiler you have.

Comment: @john: Thanks! Then I'll have a look at my build instructions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error is generated by the linker because it can not see where the definition of the constructor is located.

If you are using an IDE, you should add both .cpp files to the project so that they can be compiled together and the definition would be found by the linker.

If not, then you have to combine them yourself -assuming you are using gcc:

```
g++ cars.cpp filter.cpp
```

will combine them into one executable and should not show you *that* error

Comment: I have a `Server.h` file inside `header` sub directory and a `Server.cpp` file inside `source` sub directory. and the `main.cpp` is inside main directory. how to compile and create executable from `main.cpp` file?

Comment: @Shahriar.M Same answer: If using IDE - add all `.cpp` files to the project. If using g++ and you are located inside the main directory: `g++ source/Server.cpp main.cpp`.

You must have a `main()` function somewhere to get an executable - most likely in the file `main.cpp`.

Also, the header files should be visible from the `.cpp` files. You could add the `header` directory to the g++ command using the flag `-I`, like this: `-I ./header`.

Comment: I'm using VScode in ubuntu. this is a part of my `Makefile` before creating `header` and `source` subdirectories: `tcp_utils.o: tcp_utils.h cserv.cc
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o cserv.o cserv.cc

cserv: cserv.o tcp_utils.o
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o cserv cserv.o tcp_utils.o`. (sorry for the bad format.) how to put your command inside Makefile?

Comment: @Shahriar.M I think you should post that as a new question. This conversation no longer seems related to this particular answer and is getting too long to discuss in the comments.